# Binding controls inside a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF app with interchangeable views. A view inherits from my ViewBase class:

```
public class ViewBase : ContentControl, IView
{
    public ViewBase()
    {
        ToolbarGroups = new ObservableCollection<ToolbarGroup>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ToolbarGroup> ToolbarGroups
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ToolbarGroup>)GetValue(ToolbarGroupProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(ToolbarGroupProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolbarGroupProperty = 
                DependencyProperty.Register("ToolbarGroup", typeof(ObservableCollection<ToolbarGroup>), typeof(ViewBase));
}
```

I am binding the ToolbarGroups property to an ItemsControl in my window. It works great.

A ToolBarGroup inherits from HeaderedContentControl, and I wire them up inside a view like this:

```
<base:ViewBase x:Class="TestApp.Orders.OrderDetailsView"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:base="clr-namespace:TestApp"
               xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp.Orders"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
               x:Name="root">

    <base:ViewBase.ToolbarGroups>
        <base:ToolbarGroup Header="Group1">
            <!-- Buttons and other controls go here -->
        </base:ToolbarGroup>

        <!-- Binding to MyProp is the problem -->
        <local:PremadeToolbarGroup MyProp="{Binding}" />

        <!-- This also doesn't work -->
        <local:PremadeToolbarGroup MyProp="{Binding ElementName=root,Path=DataContext}" />
    </base:ViewBase.ToolbarGroups>

        <Grid>
            <!-- this binding works -->
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Model.FullName}" />
        </Grid>
</base:ViewBase>
```

The PremadeToolbarGroup is a XAML file that inherits from ToolbarGroup and adds some buttons. The PremadeToolbarGroup contains a dependency property called MyProp which I want to bind to the DataContext of the view its used on.

My DataContext is set to an object of type ViewModelBase, which is also the type for the MyProp dependency property.

The PremadeToolbarGroup shows up as expected, but the binding never works (MyProp is always null). Any thoughts?

Comment: Is MyProp a DependencyProperty? It must be if you want to bind to it.

Comment: Yes, MyProp is a DependencyProperty.

Comment: Done any [debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) yet?

Comment: May be I am guessing it wrong but your `ToolbarGroups` collection doesnt seem to be in the `Visual` Tree yet. Where exactly are you **hosting** it? Without such hosting `DataContext` of `ViewBase` wont inherit to the individual `ToolbarGroup` item. One way to find this out is whether bindings throwing `BindingError`s (chek in your Output window)? If they are means that they are part of the Visual Tree. Otherwise they are not.

Comment: @AngelWPF You're half-right. The problem wasn't that it's not in the visual tree, it's where it is in the visual tree. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

On my window, the view is shown in a ContentPresenter:

```
<ContentPresenter Margin="3" x:Name="ViewPresenter" />
```

The content property is set to the View via the code-behind.

As I said in my question, "I am binding the ToolbarGroups property to an ItemsControl in my window."

So I display the ToolbarGroups elsewhere in the window with this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ViewPresenter, Path=Content.ToolbarGroups}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

**The ToolbarGroup objects couldn't bind to the DataContext of the View because they were added to the visual tree outside the view.**

I was able to fix it by binding the DataContext of each item in the ItemsControl to the DataContext of the ViewPresetner content. It looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ViewPresenter, Path=Content.ToolbarGroups}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.DataContext" Value="{Binding ElementName=ViewPresenter,Path=Content.DataContext }"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

It's a bit messy but it works. I'm certainly open to a more elegant solution if anyone has one.

Answer (score 0):

Is the DataContext getting set anywhere?  Try adding `DataContext = this` to the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the DataContext is set and that the property type of MyProp matches the type used in the DataContext. Setting the DataContext is part of a more elaborate MVVM which I figured was outside the scope of the example. I can, however, successfully bind to properties on the DataContext from inside the OrderDetailsView. I just can't get MyProp to bind to the DataContext.